# requests: filter a r.json() result

Tags: python, json, python-requests

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://REDACTED.zportal.nl/api/v3/appointments?user=~me&start=1542006900&end=1542009900&access_token=REDACTED')

print(r.json())
```

When I run this code I get this result:

```
{
    "response": {
        "data": [
            {
                "locations": [
                    "018"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

full result here: http://snippi.com/s/26v74yz

Now, I only want to print the locations result. How can I filter the json result so it only shows the location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, JSON practically works just like a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping), so you can use the square brackets, `[]`, to filter it. See below.

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://REDACTED.zportal.nl/api/v3/appointments?user=~me&start=1542006900&end=1542009900&access_token=REDACTED')

locations = r.json()["response"]["data"][0]["locations"]

print(locations)
```

Comment: Thank you! I know I'm 2 years late but whatever hahaha